# Convert VMware images into ESX/ESXi format without connecting the ESX/ESXi server

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is it possible to convert various VMware images into ESXi format all locally without accessing the ESXi? Because I try to avoid the slow connection between my workstation and the ESXi server (~5MBps).

However, if I copy the ESX backup image though NFS, I can achieve roughly 20MBps. That's why I am wondering if that is feasible to do conversion all locally and move them over with simple copy command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OVF tool to convert them to OVF format and then import them as virtual appliances. At the end of the day, whether you copy them or import them, you have to transfer them over the network to the ESX host.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into OVF tool. By the way, is it possible to install ovftool on ESXi console? so I can execute the conversion on server to eliminate using management network connection. I found the network connection through VIC are rather slow...

Comment: I don't believe you can install it directly on ESX. You could try creating a Linux or Windows VM, installing it, converting your existing VM's and importing them directly from the datastore from the Linux or windows vm. Here's a link to the OVF guide:

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/ovf10/ovftool_10_userguide.pdf